# Is there a way to know if a state is active without catching ContextNotActiveException?

Tags: java-ee-6, cdi, jboss-weld

I would like to know if the `RequestScoped` context is currently active in a method or not.

At the moment, here is what I do :

```java
@Inject private BeanManager beanManager;

public boolean isRequestScopeActive() {
    try {
        if (beanManager.getContext(RequestScoped.class).isActive()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } catch (final ContextNotActiveException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I think it's a bit heavy to catch a `ContextNotActiveException` just to know if a scope is active or not.

Do you have any better way to know the state (active or not) of a context in CDI ?

Comment: RequestScoped should pretty much always be active, unless you're doing something via an async event. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Yes I'm trying to detect that because potentially I'm in an async event or in a scheduled one... see https://issues.jboss.org/browse/SEAMPERSIST-78

Comment: In that case, what you have is probably the best solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the only option we have in CDI 1.0 is to catch the ContextNotActiveException.

Your solution should work.

This actually ends up being a problem because scope implementation is not available for injection.

E.g. You can't just `@Inject RequestScopedContextImpl rq;` and check the `rq.isActive()` method, because we don't have access to that class without knowing the implementation details of CDI itself.