# Clean way of injecting/checking for presence of a HttpServletRequest with CDI from code that can be called outside a request?

Tags: jakarta-ee, wildfly, cdi, weld

I have a piece of code that can be called both within and outside a HTTP request, but wants to access information in the HttpServletRequest if it is available. My first attempt was the following:

```
@Inject
private Instance<HttpServletRequest> httpReq;

void doSomethingIfInRequest(){
  if (httpReq.isUnsatisfied()){
    return;
  }
  httpReq.get()
  // ...
}
```

However, even outside a request, `isUnsatisfied()` returns `false`, leading `get()` to throw `org.jboss.weld.exceptions.IllegalStateException: WELD-000710: Cannot inject HttpServletRequest outside of a Servlet request`.

I can solve this by catching the exception or creating another class that holds the request but was wondering whether CDI/Weld offers something to deal with this.

Answer (score 2):

`HttpServletRequest` is a so called built-in bean. CDI (Weld) provides it for you. It is always present and detected, hence `Instance.isUnsatisfied()` is going to be `false`.

You can glance at the implementation (for Weld 3) [here](https://github.com/weld/core/blob/master/modules/web/src/main/java/org/jboss/weld/module/web/HttpServletRequestBean.java). The short story is - context state (`RequestScoped`) is checked and based on the result, you either get your bean, or the exception you are seeing.

Solution - best way is probably to check whether context is active, but you probably cannot avoid catching the exception if it's not.
This can be achieved for instance via `BeanManager`:

```
@Inject
BeanManager bm;

public boolean isReqScopeActive() {
  try {
    return bm.getContext(RequestScoped.class).isActive();
  } catch (ContextNotActiveException e) {
    // this is expected response to bm.getContext() if that context is inactive
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah, I just found pretty much the same question on SO and with same conclusion - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11507109/is-there-a-way-to-know-if-a-state-is-active-without-catching-contextnotactiveexc

Comment: Note that RequestScope might still be active even when no HttpRequest exists. For example, receiving a JMS message in a MDB also has an active RequestScope.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the solution by Siliarus, the following code can be used to check whether the current context is HttpServletRequestContext or not.

```
@Inject
BeanManager bm;

public boolean isHttpRequestScopeIsActive() {
        if (isHttpRequestScopeActive == null) {

            try {
                Context context = bm.getContext(RequestScoped.class);
                isHttpRequestScopeActive = context instanceof HttpRequestContextImpl;
            } catch (ContextNotActiveException e) {
                isHttpRequestScopeActive = false;
            }

        }
        return isHttpRequestScopeActive;

    }
```